# How to perform SUM in calculated column such that the SUM is performed for that row rather than across all rows?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to learn about calculated column and measures.

In the data table, when I create a calculated column with following DAX SUM(Sale[salesamt]), then for each row it will do a SUM showing the total sum across all rows.

For SUM to be applicable for each row, rather than all rows, what is the technique to use: It is to use SUMX or to use CALCULATE?

Should there be context transition - if so then we must use CALCULATE or SUMX?

Comment: SUM[salesamt] is not a valid DAX expression.

Comment: It's an example, updated now

Comment: It depends on what you want to achive. But, in general, if you want to do a row by row sum you need to use the `SUMX` function. Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax)

Answer (score 1):

A calculated column (as opposed to a measure) will operate on the data in a single row without the use of *any* aggerate functions.

[image]

SUMX would be used in a measure where you wanted to iterate over the table resolve some expression on each row and then sum those results into a single value.

[image]